# How to calculate a personalized PageRank over millions of nodes?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pagerank

I have a sparse graph containing about a million nodes and 10 million edges. I want to calculate a *personalized* PageRank for each node, where by personalized PageRank at node n I mean:

```
# x_0 is a column vector of all zeros, except a 1 in the position corresponding to node n
# adjacency_matrix is a matrix with a 1 in position (i, j) if there is an edge from node i to node j

x_1 = 0.5 * x_0 + 0.5 * adjacency_matrix * x_0
x_2 = 0.5 * x_0 + 0.5 * adjacency_matrix * x_1
x_3 = 0.5 * x_0 + 0.5 * adjacency_matrix * x_2

# x_3 now holds the personalized PageRank scores

# i'm basically approximating the personalized PageRank by running this for only 3 iterations
```

I tried coding this up using NumPy, but it was taking too long to run. (about 1 second to calculate the personalized PageRank for each node)

I also tried changing x_0 to be matrix (by combining the column vectors of several different nodes), but this also didn't help much, and actually made the computation take much longer. (possibly because the matrix gets dense fairly quickly, and so it no longer fits in RAM? I'm not sure)

Is there another suggested way to calculate this, preferably in Python? I also thought about going the non-matrix approach to PageRank calculation, by doing a kind of simulated random walk for three iterations (i.e., I start each node with a score of 1, then propagate this score to its neighbors, etc.), but I'm not sure if this would be any faster. Would it be, and if so, why?

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought a "PageRank" algorithm would be best viewed as a Directed Graph http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph (possibly with appropriate weighting).

I like the `networkx` library at http://networkx.lanl.org

You'll find it also has a "PageRank" example under algorithms which you may be able to adapt.

Comment: Yep, I have a directed graph. Hmm, I didn't try networkx, but I did try igraph's personalized PageRank algorithm. I had the same problem, though -- it was pretty slow. (And from what I understand -- I might be wrong -- igraph is typically faster.)

Comment: @grautur Should be easy to prove - I believe `networkx` will take data from a numpy array to build a graph... Have to admit, I've never had a million nodes though... (so can't vouch for it - was just throwing the option in the ring)

Answer (score 1):

In your case, using the simulated random walk iterative approach should work fine, if your data is stored in the right way. When you have very few edges compared to the number of nodes (as in your case), I don't think the matrix approach is a good choice, since it is a very sparse matrix and yet practically this approach means that you are checking the existence of a node from i to j for any i and j. (By the way, I'm not sure how much running time those multiplications by zero really take.)

If you have your data stored in a way that for each node object, you have a list of the destinations of its outgoing links, the random walk simulation approach will be rather quick. Ignoring the damping factor, this is what you will be actually doing in each iteration of your random walk simulation:

```
for node in nodes:
    for destination in node.destinations:
        destination.pageRank += node.pageRank/len(destinations)
```

The time complexity of each iteration is then O(n*k) where in your case n=1m and k=10. This sounds good, if I'm not missing anything here.